# GridView Binding isn't working

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, gridview, mvvm

Here's my MainWindow.cs:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new MultipleProjectViewModel();
    }
```

My ViewModel:

```
 public class MultipleProjectViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<Project> _projectCollection;
    public MultipleProjectViewModel()
    {
        ProjectCollection = new ObservableCollection<Project>();
        ProjectCollection.Add(new Project(){Name = "baba",Description = "lala"});
    }
    public ObservableCollection<Project> ProjectCollection
    {
        get { return this._projectCollection; }
        set
        {
            if(_projectCollection != value)
            {
                _projectCollection = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(()=> ProjectCollection);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My model:

```
 public class Project
{
    public string Name { get; set; } // Project Name
    public string Description { get; set; } // Project Description
}
```

My view:

```
        <ListView ItemsSource="ProjectCollection">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>

                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Description" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Description}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

So why is the binding isn't working? I just see a blank GridView when I compile this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ProjectCollection}">
```

Comment: Oh crap... hahaha, I was just going to comment that I already wrote that, but haven't noticed I missed the "Binding" keyword.. Thank you!